# Optimal update frequency

Tags: computer-science, data-mining

I have a dataset on which a data mining operation is frequently performed. I want to base the frequency of performing the data mining operation on the frequency with which the data is updated. Is there any equation that would give me the optimal mining frequency on the basis of the data update frequency? If not, and I wanted to derive my own, how would I go about it? What if I wanted to include more variables? I just need some pointers to some reading materials if there are any available. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a CS problem even though it sounds like one (unless it's a homework problem... I'll assume you have a real world problem to solve). I assume if you are "data mining" you are doing something more than just running queries against a live OLTP database (such as setting up a cube on a separate system). It's going to boil down to a user problem. The answer is going to depend on:

- The patterns in the data you are capturing (is it cyclical i.e. hourly/daily/weekly). Updates more frequent than once a cycle will probably be not be useful. Similarly if it's event based, and events are not happening continuously, updating your mining system more frequently than the incoming events will be useless.
- Can you collect the data to transform it to the data-mining setup without bogging down users or systems writing the original data? If not, you need to do this when system load is low. If you are analyzing logs, or utilizing automatic replication (i.e. oracle streams)  you are probably not constrained here.
- When can the folks/processes doing the data mining stop and accept a new data-set... you can't just pull the rug out from under ongoing work and replace the data they were working on.

The answer probably won't be something you can "derive." It will come from the constraints of the users (automated or human) at either end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your points are well taken. Yes, the data-mining will not affect the users using the system, so it's ok. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what your data is like, or what your needs are -
Normally we datamine to

1. find a pattern in data
2. create a model to base future decisions on our (past)data

you only need to datamine further if

1. you have collect enough 'new' data that you might be able to find new patterns
2. you have collected enough 'new' data that the model you have no longer predicts new phenomena
3. you have developed a new technique, or modified the data in such a way that it would make sense to perform datamining again

some blind guesses:

1. I would perform the operation everytime you collect new data that would be 5% of the current dataset, i.e., if you have 10 gigabytes, perform the operation after collecting .5 GB (assuming this is feasible! (less than a day))
2. if you're not collecting new data at this scale, running the operation weekly should be relatively inexpensive and would certainly ease your mind
3. if you're collecting data at gigabyte per day scales or more, the bottleneck is then the cost of the operation. Use your judgement, maybe once a month if the operation takes more than a day. At this scale the operation itself will start costing money in computing power and the company should hire an expert.

as far as a formula, there is none but I'll refer you to the wikipedia article on [Statistical Significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance).

Comment: Thanks for this reply. It is pretty helpful. I have always been a bit wary of using statistical significance since it doesn't really tell us anything. But I appreciate your response.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the intention. Statistical significance is almost certainly a requirement for any datamining alg to find a pattern. In our context we want at least 5%, of any subset of our data, to exhibit any 'pattern'. Example, say you have a dataset about animals that is 10 GB, with 1 MB of cat data. We collect .5 GB of new data but no new cat data, do the operation. But if we collect say 50 MB of new data, but it happens to be all cat data, definitely do the operation. Because this may offer data that is Statistically significant for your cat model.

Comment: of course this too is tricky because you have to consider all possible intersections, subsets and combinations of features for your dataset. You could have as little as 1% new data, but if you happen to KNOW it's useful new data, definitely do the operation. Get me?